# JSP useBean Request scope question

Tags: jsp, scope, javabeans

I am setting the values of a java bean from a jsp page which has the useBean scope of request.

Does this mean that the java beans will lose their value once a user navigates away from this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If you have scope="session" set in the useBean tag you should be able to pass it around from jsp to jsp as long as the session is valid.